Problem when performing a push to a nested array in mongodb and nodejs
I am having a problem when performing a push to a nested array, I am trying to add one or more objects within the nested array "fieldList", when I execute the push it tells me ok but when I check it it has not updated it.
{
    _id: ObjectId('6628363d6ed5718acbd2af72'),
    label: 'Movimiento Vehicular IDAAN',
    folders: [
      {
        name: 'Datos Generales',
        fieldList: [],
        _id: ObjectId('6628367b6ed5718acbd2af9f')
      },
      {
        name: 'Datos de Vehículo y Conductor',
        fieldList: [],
        _id: ObjectId('6628555de630217d0abafcc5')
      }
    ],
    createdAt: ISODate('2024-04-23T22:29:17.213Z'),
    updatedAt: ISODate('2024-04-24T00:42:05.879Z')
  }

I am trying to add it with $push and the dot notation { $push: { "folders.fieldList": newfield}} tells me that it was executed ok but it is not added. This is the code I am using:
Object to add:
{
  "name": "Dia",
  "label": "Dia",
  "order": 11,
  "type": "number",
  "requ": true,
  "par": "Datos Generales"
}

Update Script:

export const newfieldwithfolder = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const { name, label, order, type, requ, par } = req.body;
    const query = { _id: req.params.id };
    const updateQuery = new Fields({
      name,
      label,
      order,
      type,
      requ,
      par,
    });
    const newfield = { $push: { "folders.fieldList": updateQuery } };
    const result = await Template.updateOne(query, newfield);
    console.log(result);
    res.status(201).json({ message: "Fields have been added successfully!" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: "Something went Wrong!" });
  }
};


try to add plain object instead of new Fields()

I tried but it tells me Cannot create field 'fieldList' in element {folders: [ { name: "Datos de Vehículo y Conductor", _id: ObjectId('662865780507bcae205a03be') }, { name: "Datos Generales", _id: ObjectId('662865a30507bcae205a03c1') } ]}

Your folders is an array, you can't directly update with folders.fieldList unless you are specifying which object element in the folders array to be updated, or do you want to update every element?

You can use filtered positional array update operator for your use case (adding a new object/element) to a nested array.

i agreed with @prasad_, if you want to update all elements of array folders then you could simply use "folders.$[].fieldList" otherwise you can also specify element index in it.

@VrushabhRanpariya Your comment is not clear, that how does it solve the problem. Where do you specify the element index?

Which object from the folders array do you want to update? Once this has been established it's a trivial task to push your new object into that object's fieldList array.

Sorry my bad, i mean to specify element index like : "folders.0.fieldList"

@VrushabhRanpariya Thank you!  Your solution helped me solve the problem, very grateful.  I want to ask you since I'm learning Mongo, what would be the update and delete operations for this same code?

@GianniNarracci to update and delete of array element are not the same code, for update you can use $set instead of $push but for delete is quite complicated, you can follow more on update/delete operation on array elements: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update-array/

If you specify the field name from the object in the folders array that you want to update you can use the $ positional operator to only update that element from the folders array and push your new object into that fieldList array.
Looking at your object that you want to push, you have a "par": "Datos Generales" key value so assuming this refers the folders.name field you can do:
const { name, label, order, type, requ, par } = req.body;
// also match where 'folders.name' is equal to par
const query = { 
   _id: req.params.id, 
   'folders.name': par 
};
const updateQuery = new Fields({
   name,
   label,
   order,
   type,
   requ,
   par,
});
// now use the $ positional operator to only update the folders array element that matched
const newfield = { 
   $push: { 
      "folders.$.fieldList": updateQuery 
   } 
};
const result = await Template.updateOne(query, newfield);

See HERE for a simple example using the db.collection.update() method.

here is your database object:
{
    _id: ObjectId('6628363d6ed5718acbd2af72'),
    label: 'Movimiento Vehicular IDAAN',
    folders: [
      {
        name: 'Datos Generales',
        fieldList: [],
        _id: ObjectId('6628367b6ed5718acbd2af9f')
      },
      {
        name: 'Datos de Vehículo y Conductor',
        fieldList: [],
        _id: ObjectId('6628555de630217d0abafcc5')
      }
    ],
    createdAt: ISODate('2024-04-23T22:29:17.213Z'),
    updatedAt: ISODate('2024-04-24T00:42:05.879Z')
  }

Since @Gianni didn't give specifics, there are many ways you could use it. And, as @prasad_ mentioned, I'll suggest some ideas if they fit what you're looking for:
Case 1: ( update all element of folders )
db.getCollection("template").updateOne({
    _id: ObjectId("6628363d6ed5718acbd2af72")
}, {
    $push: {
        "folders.$[].fieldList": {
            "name": "Dia",
            "label": "Dia",
            "order": 11,
            "type": "number",
            "requ": true,
            "par": "Datos Generales"
        }
    }
})

AS per your code:
export const newfieldwithfolder = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const { name, label, order, type, requ, par } = req.body;
    const query = { _id: req.params.id };
    const updateQuery = new Fields({
      name,
      label,
      order,
      type,
      requ,
      par,
    });
    const newfield = { $push: { "folders.$[].fieldList": updateQuery } }; // ← need to update here
    const result = await Template.updateOne(query, newfield);
    console.log(result);
    res.status(201).json({ message: "Fields have been added successfully!" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: "Something went Wrong!" });
  }
};

Case 2: ( update Specific element of folders by element index )
db.getCollection("template").updateOne({
    _id: ObjectId("6628363d6ed5718acbd2af72")
}, {
    $push: {
        "folders.0.fieldList": {
            "name": "Dia",
            "label": "Dia",
            "order": 11,
            "type": "number",
            "requ": true,
            "par": "Datos Generales"
        }
    }
})

AS per your code:
export const newfieldwithfolder = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const { name, label, order, type, requ, par } = req.body;
    const query = { _id: req.params.id };
    const updateQuery = new Fields({
      name,
      label,
      order,
      type,
      requ,
      par,
    });
    const newfield = { $push: { "folders.0.fieldList": updateQuery } }; // ← need to update here
    const result = await Template.updateOne(query, newfield);
    console.log(result);
    res.status(201).json({ message: "Fields have been added successfully!" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: "Something went Wrong!" });
  }
};

Case 3: ( update Specific element of folders by some condition )
db.getCollection("template").updateOne({
    _id: ObjectId("6628363d6ed5718acbd2af72"),
    "folders._id": ObjectId("6628555de630217d0abafcc5") // OR "folders.name": { $regex: 'Datos de', $options: 'i' }
}, {
    $push: {
        "folders.$.fieldList": {
            "name": "Dia",
            "label": "Dia",
            "order": 11,
            "type": "number",
            "requ": true,
            "par": "Datos Generales"
        }
    }
})

AS per your code:
export const newfieldwithfolder = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const { name, label, order, type, requ, par } = req.body;
    const query = { _id: req.params.id, "folders._id": ObjectId("6628555de630217d0abafcc5") }; // ← need to update here
    const updateQuery = new Fields({
      name,
      label,
      order,
      type,
      requ,
      par,
    });
    const newfield = { $push: { "folders.$.fieldList": updateQuery } }; // ← need to update here
    const result = await Template.updateOne(query, newfield);
    console.log(result);
    res.status(201).json({ message: "Fields have been added successfully!" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: "Something went Wrong!" });
  }
};


This is a good answer. Covers the various possible scenarios so will help others in future. You may want to include a https://mongoplayground.net/ to give examples of your code running.

@jQueeny mongoplayground.net doesn't support the updateOne method, even if I use the update method it may confuse our future visitors to use the update method or updateOne.
